# Firebase functions V2: Memory Configuration

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How to set options `{memory: "1GiB"}` on firestore triggered cloud function.

I can't find it in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade

There is an exemple for https functions but it seem to have a different syntaxe for onDocumentCreated(), etc..

```
export const statisticsDataCreated = onDocumentCreated("statistics/data", async (event) => {
  /** Do things **/
});
```

Did you find the way to achieve it ?

Comment: Anyone find the solution yet? It isn't blocking as I can change the memory allocation with the google cloud function console but i need to do it on every deploy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the document to listen for as a plain string, you can add an options object in which you set the runtime config, and specify the document to listen for using the `document` key. Like this:

```
export const firestoreTrigger = onDocumentWritten(
  {
    memory: "16GiB",
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    document:  "users/{userId}"
   },
  (event) => {
    // your logic
  }
);
```

Comment: oh that perfect, i'm going to try it right now !

Comment: Work like magic, it is the syntax i could'nt find in the documentation. Actualy even firebase support didn't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes same here, couldn't find it in the documentation. [This](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1433) github issue and digging in the type declarations finally shed light on it. When you look up `onDocumentWritten` in `node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2providers/firestore.d.ts` you see multiple overloaded function definitions for it, where `DocumentOptions` object is one possible argument. which extends `EventHandlerOptions`, which extends `GlobalOptions`, which finally has the desired fields.

Just adding it to the documentation would've been easier though ;)

Comment: for sure, it would have same me a few hours to have it in the documentation. Thank again.

Comment: Apparently my problem was that I'd written `GB` instead of `GiB` 

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:
Solution has been found.**

For now, it seems not possible to achieve it. I have contacted Firebase support, and here is their answer:

> Thanks for reaching out to Firebase support, my name is Brenda and
> I'll handle your case. As per the details you kindly shared with us,
> you are having issues when setting memory allocation to your Firestore
> trigger. Upon checking the Firebase Functions reference, the
> onDocumentUpdated method only allows two arguments: Document (or
> DocumentOptions) and the event handler.
>
> In order to set memory allocation to your Firestore triggers, you have
> two options: From source code: by using global options. More
> information can be found here. Through the Google Cloud Console. If
> you have any questions or comments regarding this, please let me know.
> I'll do my best to assist you.

As it is what @mattiagalati suggest i will accept his answer.

Answer (score -1):

As far I can see in docs here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd&hl=it#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation)

the options can be passed as the first argument before the callback function itself:

```
exports.convertLargeFile = onObjectFinalized({
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: "1GiB",
}, (event) => {
  // Do some complicated things that take a lot of memory and time
});
```

Unfortunately seems like there is no way to use the same notation for **onDocumentCreated** since the function signature (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/3e7a4b77967e46a067712445c499c5df005b8e31/src/v2/providers/firestore.ts#L162) doesn't allow the same parameter.

Checking further in the docs, I stumbled upon this page (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#set_runtime_options) which seems to suggest you have to use the **setGlobalOptions** function to apply a shared configuration across all functions deployed in the same file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was my first idea but it do not work that way.
onDocumentCreate accept only document and handler as params. Or at least in client side leading to a compilation error

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, I've edited my reply.

Comment: Thank you I don't really want to increase the memory allocation of all the function. But it is a good idea. I will stay with my walkaround who is to change the allocation in the console, it work but need to be done everytime. I have written a report to firebase I will let you know if they give me an answer.

Answer (score -3):

you can use runWith to set runtime options

```
    export const statisticsDataCreated = functions.runWith({ memory: '1GiB', timeoutSeconds: 120 }).firestore.document("statistics/data").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    /** Do things **/
});
```

Comment: This code works only for V1 functions